# Asp.net membership never logout

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, timeout

Im using forms authentication and SqlMembershipProvider, what do I need to do so the user never logout automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your cookie's expiration date using timeout on your forms element in the [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is a value for infinite?

Comment: You can use slidingExpiration, to reset/extend the expiration date/time each time the user starts a new session.  This combined with a long timeout should give you something that feels like it never expires.